# IIS looking for .cs file in compiled .net site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am building my first ASP.Net web application project in VS2010. The site has a master page which all the content pages use.

I have published it to a local Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5 - so other members of the team can have a look.

I published it using 'File System' to a directory on the server. If I look in the directory on the server, all I see are .aspx files and a few dlls - which is what I would expect.

If I go into IIS and try to browse the web application (or open a browser on my local box and go to `http://myserver/Contacts` - I get a Server Error - 'the file Contacts/MasterPage1.master.cs' does not exist.

I don't understand - why is IIS looking for a .cs file when, in a web application project - all the .cs files are compiled into a dll?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check few things:

- Check if you are you referring to master page type using `CodeFile="..."` or `CodeBehind="..."` attributes. If you are using `CodeFile` change to `CodeBehind`, or even better right click on your project and click Convert to Web project
- Try adding namespace when referring to master page ( `Inherits="Project.MasterPage"` )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using CodeBehind - and have added a namespace when referring to the master page - and published. Still looking for the .cs file though when I try to browse it.

Comment: Brillant! Got it working - I changed the Default.aspx page to reference the namespace but had not changed the master page. Changed that too and now it is working. (My problem really was that I copied pages in from a previous web site to get me started - and, as I have found out, a web application project is a different beast.

Comment: How do you 'accept the answer'? Had a look in the FAQs - can't see anthing.

Comment: You should see a check just below the votes' count to the left of the answer